# Passing a Port as a variable - AVR

Tags: c++, io, avr

Is it possible to use an AVR port as a variable which can be passed around?

For example

```
LED myLed(PORTA,7);   //myLED hooked to PORTA, Pin 7
```

I would like to make LED be able to take any PORT / Pin combination, so I would rather not hard code it in.

Note that the PORTs are defined as:

```
#define PINA  _SFR_IO8(0x00)
#define DDRA  _SFR_IO8(0x01)
#define PORTA _SFR_IO8(0x02)
```

PORTA symbol resolves to (*(volatile uint8_t *)((0x02) + 0x20))

I believe this would allow me to do something like the following, but I am unsure whether I would need the volatile keyword or not, nor whether it will actually work as expected

```
class LED{
public:
    LED(volatile uint8_t* port, uint8_t pin);
    {
        Port=port;
        Pin=pin;
    }
    void write(bool val)
    {
        if(val) (*Port) |= 1 << Pin;
        else    (*Port) &= ~(1 << Pin);
    }

private:
    uint8_t  Pin
    volatile uint8_t* Port;
}
```

Finally, is there a way to set Port / Pin as an Output from the LED Constructor?
This would involve finding the relative DDR# register for the Given PORT#.
Can I assume &DDR# will always be &PORT#-1?

Comment: you can use also a bit struct...

Comment: would you mind expanding on this?  I'm not sure what you mean by bit struct

Comment: `struct port{ UINT8 _port_1_0:1; UINT8 _port_1_2:1; ... };` - this is better/nicer in C. But if you have C++ and templates avakar example is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The register macros are basically pointers to the memory location, where the appropriate register resides, so yes, you can use `uint8_t volatile *`. However, the compiler will not generate the most efficient code this way -- it will use indirect addressing instead of direct writes.

This is what I do instead, using [avrlib](http://technika.junior.cz/trac/browser/avrlib).

```
#include <avrlib/porta.hpp>
#include <avrlib/pin.hpp>
using namespace avrlib;

typedef pin<porta, 4> led_pin;
```

Then you can use the `led_pin` typedef, e.g.

```
led_pin::set();
```

Comment: The link to the library no longer works (the site is down).

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it, im not very experienced in AVR,

```
#include <avr/io.h>

void LED(volatile uint8_t* port, uint8_t pin)
{
    // First set DDRx ; DDRx on ATmega32 is one address below port address
    *(port -1) |= (1<< pin);
    // Now set the pin high
    *port |= (1<< pin);
}

int main(void)
{
   LED(&PORTB,1);
   LED(&PORTC,2);
   LED(&PORTD,3);
    while (1) 
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ports are nothing more than I/O addresses, so all you have to do is pass the address of the I/O port to you LED constructor:

```
LED *light = new LED(&PORTA, 4);
```

Why does this work? PORTA resolves, as you already mentioned, to the dereferencing of a pointer:

```
(*(volatile uint8_t *)((0x02) + 0x20))
```

So adding an address of operator in front creates

```
&(*(volatile uint8_t *)((0x02) + 0x20))
```

which can be simplified to

```
(volatile uint8_t *)((0x02) + 0x20)
```